# Deep Neural Network Not Learning Anything

Tags: neural-networks, python, predictive-models

I am training a simple Neural network with some Dense and Dropout Layers. But on running the fit function, there is no training taking place. My Model is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

Model = Sequential()

Model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))

for i in range(4):
    Model.add(Dense(2**(5+i), activation='relu'))
    Model.add(Dropout(0.5))

Model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

Model.summary()
```

```
Model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
)
```

```
my_callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2),
]
Model.fit(x=X, y=Y, batch_size=32, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=my_callbacks)
Result of Training are:
```

```
Epoch 1/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
Epoch 2/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
Epoch 3/20
26/26 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 9.3856 - accuracy: 0.3845 - val_loss: 9.4884 - val_accuracy: 0.3778
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f94a623ffd0>
I tried to see what the Model is predicting:
```

```
Model.predict(X)[:10]
```

Results:

```
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

and so on (all predictions are 1.0).

My input dataframes are:

```
X.head(5)
```

```
    0            1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10          11
0   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    -0.743497   0.743497    -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    -0.611972   0.481288    -0.445  -0.503402
1   1.747178    -0.518084   -1.087045   1.344995    -1.344995   1.96167     -0.32204    -1.526692   0.630431    0.481288    -0.445  0.734222
2   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    1.344995    -1.344995   -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    -0.301371   -0.479087   -0.445  -0.490356
3   1.747178    -0.518084   -1.087045   1.344995    -1.344995   -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    0.397481    0.481288    -0.445  0.382778
4   -0.572351   -0.518084   0.919925    -0.743497   0.743497    -0.50977    -0.32204    0.655011    0.397481    -0.479087   -0.445  -0.487940
```

```
Y.head(10):
```

```
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    1
Name: Survived, dtype: int64
```

I am not finding the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the details of Keras specifically, but I see that your output is one node with softmax activation. The $i^{\mathit{th}}$ element of softmax on a preactivation vector $a$ of length $n$ is:
\begin{align}
\text{softmax}(a)_i & = \frac{\exp(a_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(a_i)}
\end{align}
If $n=1$, we get:
\begin{align}
\text{softmax}(a)_1 & = \frac{\exp(a_1)}{\sum_{i=1}^1 \exp(a_i)}\\
& = \frac{\exp(a_1)}{\exp(a_1)}\\
& = 1
\end{align}
Softmax is useful when you have multiple outputs, not one.

You should be able to just remove the softmax from your output, and specify that the `BinaryCrossEntropyLoss` is from logits (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy).